# Is it legal to convert a pointer/reference to a fixed array size to a smaller size

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is it legal as per the C++ standard to convert a pointer or reference to a fixed array (e.g. `T(*)[N]` or `T(&)[N]`) to a pointer or reference to a smaller fixed array of the same type and CV qualification (e.g. `T(*)[M]` or `T(&)[M]`)?

Basically, **would this always be well-formed for all instantiations of `T`** (regardless of layout-type):

```cpp
void consume(T(&array)[2]);

void receive(T(&array)[6])
{
  consume(reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(array));   
}
```

I don't see any references to this being a valid conversion in:

- [`expr.reinterpret.cast`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast),
- [`expr.static.cast`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.static.cast),
- [`conv.array`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.array), or even
- [`basic.types`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types)

However, it appears that all major compilers accept this and generate proper code even when optimized when using `T = std::string` (<kbd>[compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TW7dPW)</kbd>)<sup>(not that this proves much, if it is undefined behavior)</sup>.

It's my understanding that this should be illegal as per the type-system, since an object of `T[2]` was never truly created, which means a reference of `T(&)[2]` would be invalid.

---

I'm tagging this question [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) because this is the version I am most interested in the answer for, but I would be curious to know whether this answer is different in newer versions a well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223642/discussion-on-question-by-human-compiler-is-it-legal-to-convert-a-pointer-refere).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s not much to say here except **no**, in any language version: the types are simply unrelated.  C++20 does allow conversion from `T (*)[N]` to `T (*)[]` (and similarly for references), but that doesn’t mean you can treat two different `N`s equivalently.  The closest you’re going to get to a “reference” for this rule is [conv.array]/1 (“The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.”, which `T[2]` does not exist in your example) and a *note* in [defns.undefined] (“Undefined behavior may be expected when this document omits any explicit definition of behavior”).

Part of the reason that compilers don’t “catch” you is that such `reinterpret_cast`s *are* valid to **return** to the real type of an object after another `reinterpret_cast` used to “sneak” it through an interface that expects a pointer or reference to a different type (but doesn’t *use* it as that type!).  That means that the code as given is legitimate, but the obvious sort of definition for `consume` and caller for `receive` would *together* cause undefined behavior.  (The other part is that optimizers often leave code alone that’s *always* undefined unless it can eliminate a branch.)

Comment: If you happen to have any supporting references for this answer, I would be happy to accept this answer. This was my conclusion as well -- though I can't find anything to confirm or deny it. Some of the discussions relating to conversions of standard layout types suggests this may be valid as long as `T` is a standard layout type

Comment: @Human-Compiler: How can there be any more of a reference here than for `int` and `void (*)()`?  They’re just unrelated types.  The bit you’re probably remembering about standard-layout types has to do with reading the wrong member of a union, which is poorly specified at the best of times and plainly irrelevant here.

Comment: For standard layout types, I am referring to [`expr.reinterpret.cast` §5.2.10/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) which states that as long as `T1` and `T2` are standard layout objects with compatible alignments, that you may `reinterpret_cast` a pointer of `T1` to `T2`. That said, it only states that the pointer conversion is valid -- not that the pointer itself may be used. As far as I'm aware, the common-initial sequence may only be accessed in the case of a `union` but not a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @Human-Compiler: That’s a fair point—it constrains the set of (pairs of) types where the `reinterpret_cast` round trip is guaranteed by the `void*` wording.  That doesn’t mean—at all—that you can **use** the result that points to the wrong type.

Comment: I think in the absence of any contradictory information, your explanation seems the most sensible and fits with what I was already pretty certain was correct. Thank you for your answer! I do wish there was a more normative reference we could refer to in order to emphasize that this is the correct reading, rather than treating this as a negative filter for all things _not_ specified.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: You’re welcome; I suppose one could extend the note (now) in [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7 with text like in the one in /6, but it’s really a mistake to look there for the aliasing rules since it’s the use of the result that is prohibited.  (The point usually cited for the latter is [basic.lval]/11, but we don’t get as far as “accessing” anything here.)

Comment: _“The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.”, which `T[2]` does not exist in your example_ Why the (non-)existence of `T[2]` matters?  I think the only reasonable way to read the standard sentence is “The result is a pointer to the first element of the array [to which the glvalue refers].” Assuming `array` denotes a really existing array object of type `T[6]` (and naming such object as `array`), `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(array)` lvalue denotes the same object. So [conv.array] applied to such lvalue gives a pointer to the first element of `array`.

Comment: _The closest you’re going to get to a “reference” for this rule is [conv.array]/1_ I think the closest one can get here is [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.ref#5.sentence-3). Which is the subject of [CWG453](http://wg21.link/cwg453). But if one doesn't bind a reference and just uses `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(array)` as an operand of the subscripting operator, I don't see any problems.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: I don’t agree that a glvalue of type `T[2]` “knows” that it actually refers to a `T[6]` (via `reinterpret_cast`) so that [conv.array]/1 is meaningful; I don’t disagree that the wording can be read that way (just as for your report about a signed/unsigned mismatch), but I think it’s a defect that it doesn’t say something more like “of the array *of the type of the glvalue* to which the glvalue refers”.

Comment: _I don’t agree that a glvalue of type `T[2]` “knows” that it actually refers to a `T[6]`_ If you mean that I read wording incorrectly, m/b the first 2 paragraphs of [this answer](https://lists.isocpp.org/core/2017/05/2127.php) would convince you. Or what do you mean by "knows"?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: I mean more narrowly that the pointer value, which is certainly “pointer to whatever `T[6]` object”, cannot be “used” by a glvalue of type `T[2]` just because they both happen to be array types.  Or so should be our interpretation, because the alternative is uselessly baroque.

Comment: @DavisHerring _Or so should be our interpretation, because the alternative is uselessly baroque_ This should be a question to core, but I don't understand why a pointer of type `U` pointing to an object of unrelated type `T` is legal and not baroque, while a glvalue of type `T[2]` denoting an object of type `T[6]` (and used in [conv.array]) is baroque. `auto p = reinterpret_cast<U(&)[M]>(o);` for `o` of type `T[N]` should be equivalent to `auto p =reinterpret_cast<U*>(o);`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer If you feel this answer is insufficient or incorrect and wish to offer an alternative, please feel free to post your own answer. This can help avoid this turning into extended discussion. If an answer can be justified with definitive references, I am more than happy to upvote and/or change the "correct answer" based on the merits and value of that answer.

Answer (score 2):

A late additional answer, that rather yields the quality of a comment but would exceed the allowed content amount by far:

At first: Great question! It's remarkable, that such a quite obvious issue is hard to be verified and generates a lot of confusion even among experts. Worth to mention, that I've seen code of that category quite often already...

**Some words about undefined behavior first**

I think at least the question about the pointer usage is a great example where one has to admit, that theoretical undefined behavior from one aspect of the language can sometimes be "beaten" by two other strong aspects:

1. Are there other standard clauses that reduce the degree of UB for the aspect of interest for several cases? Are there maybe clauses whose priorities within the standard are ambiguous to each other even? (There are several prominent examples still existing in C++20, see conversion-type-id handling for operator auto() for instance...).
2. Are there (Turing-) provable arguments, that any theoretical and practical compiler realization has to behave as you expect since there are other constraints from the language, that have to determine it that way? Saying that even if UB can quirky mean, the compiler could apply "I can do what I want here, even the biggest mess" for your case, it might be provable, that the ensuring of other specified(!) language aspects determines that to be at least effectively impossible.

So with respect to point 2, there's an often underrated aspect: What are the constraints (if definable) by the model of the abstract machine, that determine the outcome of any theoretical (compiler-) implementation for the given code?

**So, many words so far, but does anything from 1) apply to your concrete case (the pointer way)?**

As multiple times users mentioned within the comments, a chance for that lies here [basic.types#basic.compound-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#basic.compound-4):

> Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> ...
>
> (4.4) there exists an object c such that a and c are
> pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.

That's the simple rule of transitivity. Can we actually find such a c (for arrays)?

Within the same section, the standard says further on:

> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
> address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
> to the other via a reinterpret_­cast. [ Note: An array object and its
> first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have
> the same address.  — end note ]

demolishing our dreams here of our approach via the pointer-to-the-first-element - usage. There isn't such a c for arrays.

Do we have another chance? You mentioned [expr.reinterpret.cast#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) :

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
> a different type.70 When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is
> converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is static_cast<cv
> T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)) if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout
> types ([basic.types]) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no
> stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void. Converting a
> prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1
> and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are
> no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
> original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
> conversion is unspecified.

This looks promising at first glance but the devil is in the details. That solely ensures that you can apply the pointer conversion since the alignment requirements for both arrays are equal, but not refer to interconvertibility (i.e. object usage itself) a priori.
As Davis already said: with the pointer to the first element, one could still use `reinterpret_cast` as some kind of a fake fascade fully standard compliant as long as the wrong type `pointer to T[2]` is only really used as a forwarder and all actual use cases refer to the element pointer via an according `reinterpret_cast` and as long as all use cases "are aware" of the fact, that the actual type was a `T[4]`. Trivial to see, that this is still hacky as hell for many scenarios. At least a type aliasing in order to emphasize the forwarding quality would be recommended here.

So a strict interpretation of the standard here is: It's undefined behavior with the note that we all know that it should work well with all common modern compilers on many common platforms (I know, the latter was not your question).

**Do we have some chances according to my point 2) about effective "weak UB" from above?**

I don't think so as long as only the abstract machine is on focus here. For instance, IMO there's no restriction from the standard, a compiler/environment could not handle (abstract) allocation schemes differently between arrays of different size (changed intrinsics for threshold sizes for instance) while still ensuring alignment requirements. To be very quirky here, one could say a very exotic compiler could be allowed to refer to underlying dynamic storage duration mechanisms even for scoped objects that appear to be on that what we know as stack. Another related possible issue could be the question about proper deallocation of arrays of dynamic storage duration here (see the similar debate about UB in the context of inheritance from classes that do not provide virtual destructors). I highly doubt that it's trivial to validate, that the standard guarantees a valid cleanup here a priori, i.e. effectively calling ~T[4] for your example for all cases.

Comment: I'm not sure considerations of type 2 really belong in questions specifically tagged language-lawyer, with specific phrasing like "according to the C++ Standard" and "well-formed", and not also mentioning other things like "safe", "in practice", etc.

Comment: @aschepler I agree a bit but I thought it emphasizes that the initial assumption is wrong in terms of standard compliance even a layer before the strict ruling is applied. Be aware of the fact, that my point 2) is still a totally formalistic one (see mathematical proof systems), that has nothing to do with actual compilers a priori.