# Is it safe to reinterpret_cast as a smaller array? Is there a better option?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reinterpret-cast

So, let's assume I have a custom vector type:

```cpp
template <class D, size_t N>
class Vector {
public:
    
    Vector(const D* arrayPtr)
    {
        memcpy(m_array.data(), arrayPtr, sizeof(D)*N);
    }

    ... operators, methods, etc ...

    std::array<D, N> m_array;
};
```

So, I instantiate a new `Vector<double, 4>` pointer. However, sometimes I want to treat it as a `Vector<double, 3>`. Is it safe to do the following?

```cpp
Vector4* myVec4 = new Vector4(1, 2, 3, 4);
Vector3* myVec3 = reinterpret_cast<Vector3*>(myVec4);
```

I would assume "maybe", since the class is contiguous in memory, and doesn't have any virtual methods. However, I want to be very sure before I make any risky moves.

Comment: I would assume not, since this is violating strict-aliasing. I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539646/1678770) a few weeks ago, and the conclusion was that this is not a safe cast.

Comment: Good candidate for a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

Comment: `template <class D> class Vector<D, 3> { std::string name; };` highlights pretty well why this is banned.

Comment: No, the `reinterpret_cast` is not safe.    As a rule of thumb, if it is necessary to beat the compiler into submission by adding a `_cast` to force it to accept a conversion, then using the result of the `_cast` is unsafe.    (A more formal description would be that you are breaking strict-aliasing rules).

Comment: @Peter: I don't think that's accurate. `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` are pretty much always safe.  It's only `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` that's dangerous.

Comment: @MooingDuck - `static_cast` involving pointers can be unsafe (e.g. using the pointer that results from `static_cast<X *>(address_that_is_not_of_an_X)`).   But, in any event, I was referring to use of casting to force the compiler to accept a conversion that (without the cast) is formally a diagnosable error.  `dynamic_cast` has its share of concerns (such as being a code smell) but is not usually used to bludgeon a compiler into submission in that way.

Comment: @Peter That only applies to `void*`. As long as you don't static_cast a `void*`, then its safe: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17e9f0e51289ba67

Comment: @Human-Compiler Wow, small world! Your question is pretty much the same thing. It's a disappointing answer, but not surprising. I'll just have to either use a converting constructor, or a viewer type class.

Comment: @MooingDuck `static_cast` is "pretty much always safe"? I doubt that in this absolute manner. What do you expect to happen for invalid downcasts ...? Be lucky with a fast detectable heap corruption here...

Comment: @Secundi: I stand corrected. I was unaware that a `static_cast` worked at all for downcasts. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3c5bd033c523d07

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that would not be safe because accessing the object through the incompatible pointer would result in undefined behaviour.

To achieve something similar, you could instead use a class such as `Vector3View` that indirectly refers to the larger vector.

Comment: That's not surprising, and I was thinking of following a pattern like that, it would just be more effort than it's worth for the time being. Thanks!